# Controlling filter date range via the url parameters using Django views & templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

So, I'm filtering by date below. But, how do I make it possible for a user to control the date range **via the url**. So, for example:

```
 http://fakeurl.net/?start=10-1-15&end=10-5-15
```

Where the user can change the parameters in the url to dictate between what date range the objects will show on the site. Here is my view:

```
class FakeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    template = "fake.html"

    stuff = ObjectName.objects.all().order_by('approved')
    number_of_stuff = request.GET.get('number_of_stuff, default="10")

    start = datetime.date(2010, 1, 1)
    end = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)
    stuff = ObjectName.objects.filter(created__range=(start, end))

    return render(request, template, {'stuff': stuff, 'number_of_stuff': number_of_stuff})
```

Here is what is in my template:

```
    {% for stuff in stuff|dictsortreversed:"created"|slice:number_of_stuff %}
               {{ stuff.whatever }}
    <% endfor %>
```

Do I need to do anther request.GET.get() for the date range? How do I break it up between start and finish? And how would it integrate into the template?

**Figured it out:**
So, this is nothing fancy, but for my purposes will work fine:

```
    end_date = request.GET.get('end_date', default="2100-1-1")
    start_date = request.GET.get('start_date', default="1850-1-1")

    stuff = Stuff.objects.filter(approved__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

And then just pass the start and end date variables to the render function

Comment: I'm not sure that getting a raw data from request.GET is secure. What if user will make a mistake in the date value? Like ?end_date=2015-05-112. I still advise to move code that captures GET attributes, validates them, turns it to appropriate python type and set a default value to the form code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Django forms to capture and validate your "start" and "finish" for date filtering.

So just add a simple form:

```
from django import forms

class DateFilterForm(forms.Form):
    start = forms.DateField()
    finish = forms.DateField()
```

Then in your view just pass your GET attributes to this form:

```
...
form = DateFilterForm(request.GET)
if not form.is_valid():
    # here goes either some error handling or setting default filter values
else:
    start = form.cleaned_data['start']
    finish = form.cleaned_data['finish']
...
```

In your templates you can use the same form and customize start and finish fields with some jquery datepicker plugin.

Comment: @MichaelSebastian You should still use it for validation without putting it into template.

Comment: Ok thanks - I figured this out going to post my answer